# Ubuntu 12.04 doesn't see the second monitor

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, nvidia-graphics-card

I've got vanilla Ubuntu 12.04 lts, GeForce GTX560 and Core -i7 2600's integrated card (on desktop based on ASUS P8H61-MX).

The system seems to detect NVidia videocard (lspci shows that there is nvidia card which uses nouveau), but the display connected to Nvidia is off and system doesn't detect it.

How can I make Ubuntu detect the second display?

PS integrated card connected with display via vga and nvidia connected with the second one via DVI